# Introduction to functional interpretations

Tags: reference-request, proof-theory

Any good recomendations for an introduction to functional interpretations? I understand this is a little vague but i haven't had much contact with the area. I am particularly interested in the intuitionistic logic and wanted to get to know (possibly with some historical context also) some classical interpretations, namely: Modified Realizability, Gödel's functional interpretation and Diller-Nahm interpretation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try *Ulrich Kohlenbach*: "[Applied Proof Theory](http://books.google.de/books?id=X54vfY8G7CYC&lpg=PR2&hl=de&pg=PR13#v=onepage&q&f=false): Proof Interpretations and their Use in Mathematics". Springer Monographs in Mathematics, 2008. Probably it is a big shot for your question, but it addresses

- Systems of intuitionistic logic and arithmetic
- No-Counterexample Interpretation (Kreisel)
- Modified Realizability (Kreisel)
- Functional (Dialectica) Interpretation (Gödel)
- Applications of Functional Interpretation in mathematics

The historical context is usually outlined at the end of the respective chapters.